# How to type check a function in python3 that has an optional argument initially set to None?

Tags: python, python-3.x, typechecking

How do I use type checking in a function that has optional parameters? For instance:

```
def do_something_cool(number1: int, letter1: str, seed=None: (None, int) )-> str:
    return
```

will fail because of `(None, int)`. What is the correct syntax for this?

Comment: Right now your code fails because you have mismatched parentheses (you never close the parameter list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With most type checkers the following works without explicitly saying that the value is nonable:

```
def do_something_cool(number1: int, letter1: str, seed: int = None) -> str:
    return
```

However, you can also explicitly specify that the value is nonable:

```
from typing import Optional

def do_something_cool(number1: int, letter1: str, seed: Optional[int] = None) -> str:
    return
```

Big warning here: `typing.Optional` actually means **Nonable** and has nothing to do with the fact that your value has a default value (so it does not mean "optional"). See [this discussion](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/275#issuecomment-244736968). One way to remember it is to think of `Optional` as applying to the type, not to the value.

[PEP484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) was previously recommending the implicit writing, but now recommends that you explicitly states `Optional` when your value is Nonable. See [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#union-types).